# Azure Resource Pipeline trigger not working

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

I have a question on the pipeline resource trigger and I have 3 branches in the single repo in the project.
Repo name: test-repo
Branch name's:

```
- vishnu/branch1
  - branch1.yaml
- vishnu/branch2
  - branch2.yaml
- vishnu/branch3
  - child.yaml
```

Pipelines created for all the 3 pipelines are named as follows:

```
poc_branch1 (branch1.yaml)
poc_branch2 (branch2.yaml)
poc_child (child.yaml)
```

The `child.yaml` contains the resource trigger like below:

```
resources:
  pipelines:    
    - pipeline: poc_branch1
      source: poc_branch1 # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact.
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - refs/heads/vishnu/branch1
   - pipeline: poc_branch2
      source: poc_branch2 # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact.
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - refs/heads/vishnu/branch2
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
trigger: none
pr: none
stages:
  - stage: Consume_Artifact
    displayName: Consume Artifact From Main Pipeline
    jobs:
      - job: Consume
        displayName: Consume
         steps:
           - task: PowerShell@2
             displayName: 'Extracting the Triggered Pipeline alias'
             inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |                
                Write-output "This pipeline has been triggered by: $(Resources.TriggeringAlias)"
```

Ideally, `poc_child` pipeline should be triggered once the poc_branch1 or poc_branch2 pipelines get completed. But it's not happening.

What might be a reason?

**If I keep child.yaml in poc_branch1 where branch1.yaml file exists. And point the child.yaml to poc_child  pipeline, and the trigger works.**

Appreciate the input.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what, but overall why, you are trying to achieve this (this way). I find it hard to understand why you are creating dependencies between branches this way.

Comment: @promicro, Thanks for the interest on this.

Okay let me give a context, say I have multiple clients which they will have they own pipelines (Main pipeline). In their pipelines they will pass the parameters along with their logic and to store those in to the artifacts. The child pipeline which is a centralized one which is not hidden from those clients. But in the child pipeline we will specify the main pipelines(as configured in the resource trigger). Once the main pipeline is successfully completed, the child pipeline read those artifacts and process the inputs further internally.

Comment: I did not tried it out yet due to other task. Will update on the same.

Answer (score 0):

> What might be reason?

The reason is when the two pipelines are in the same repository, **the triggered pipeline version in the same branch as the triggering pipeline is run**. That means, when poc_branch1 completed based on branch1, poc_child will be triggered and run based on branch1 as well. In your scenario, child.yaml only stores in branch3 but don't have other child.yaml versions in branch1 or branch2. Thus, poc_child can't run based on branch1 and branch2 even if branch1 and branch2 triggered poc_child. You could refer to [Branch considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#branch-considerations) for details.

> If I keep child.yaml in poc_branch1 where branch1.yaml file is exists.
> And point the child.yaml to poc_child pipeline, the trigger works.

Not clear about it. If you keep child.yaml in both branch1 and branch3 and the completed pipeline met the resource trigger filter, then, it should be expected. Please share more information about the details.

Comment: Thanks Suki Ji-MSFT for your input. let me check the Branch Considerations once. and come back